# What's the simplest Typescript idiom for checking if an array exists and has nonzero length?

Tags: typescript

I frequently have a collection that might be either undefined or empty. So I write this:

```
if ((thingies?.length ?? 0) > 0) ...
```

I guess that's not so bad in the grand scheme, but it ain't pretty. What I *really* want is a Bash-like operator that means "this variable exists, is an array, and has at least one element":

```
if (thingies#) ... // it's safe to access thingies[0]
```

Pretty sure that's not a thing. But what's the most concise Typescript expression of this?

Comment: `if (array?.length)` evaluates to a boolean true if it's an array with at least one item. 0 or undefined would both return false, so only positive numbers remain

Answer (score 4):

I would simply write it like this:

```
if (Array.isArray(thingies) && thingies.length > 0) {
  [...]
}
```

Not the shortest way but way more clear (and more correct) in my opinion.

**Edit:**

If it feels too long and you need it often, you can also simply define it as a function:

```
import {isNonEmptyArray} from "./utils";

if (isNonEmptyArray(thingies)) {
  [...]
}
```

```
// utils.ts
export const isNonEmptyArray = (array: unknown): array is unknown[] => (
  Array.isArray(array) && array.length > 0
)
```

Comment: Don't forget the type predicate for `isNonEmptyArray`.

Comment: Ah right, I added it :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that both `undefined` and `0` are falsy values, you can just write:

```
if (array?.length)
```

Either `array` is `undefined` and this will return `false`, or it is defined and it will return `false` if `length === 0`.

**Edit:**
If you first wish to ensure that the object is an array, you can perform a check using `Array.isArray` beforehand:

```
if (Array.isArray(object) && object.length)
```

Comment: what if its an object {length:7}.

Comment: Well, as long as the Typescript definition of your object's type includes a `length: number` property, then this condition will work just fine.

Comment: what I mean is that this will allow non-arrays to pass the condition.

Comment: I see, you are definitely right, my solution does not check that the object reference is an `Array`.

Comment: I believe the check for it being an array will make the `?.` unneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, a year later: I usually use `thing?.length` now, but I also frequently make use of the lodash [`size(thing)`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-size-method/) and [`isEmpty(thing)`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-isempty-method/) methods for this. That's particularly helpful when particularly when `thing` might be something else, like a set or an object, or when I need to check if the length is greater than `n`, where `n > 0`:

```
if ((thing?.length ?? 0) > 1) ...            // :(
if (isArray(thing) && thing.length > 1) ...  // :|
if (size(thing) > 1) ...                     // :)
```